# Android: Allocated memory of app used by other apps

Tags: android, performance, adb, ram

The Allocated memory is shown to to be almost completely utilized even on idle condition. The logcat shows a lot of external activity which is not related to my app but some other OS processes.

I am using Android 6.0.1 on Redmi Note 3 MIUI v8.

I would like to know where could this memory leak be occurring.

[Allocated Memory in Android Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zry4V.png)

The following is the logcat when the app is idle. My app package is in.co.pamper.droid which cannot be seen in it.

```
12-06 20:15:33.862 3017-3017/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :1signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 30 -81 -11 68 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
12-06 20:15:35.083 27948-27948/? W/subsystem_ramdu: type=1400 audit(0.0:174250): avc: denied { read } for name="/" dev="tmpfs" ino=10822 scontext=u:r:subsystem_ramdump:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
12-06 20:15:35.089 27948-27948/? I/subsystem_ramdump: Usage:./system/bin/subsystem_ramdump [arg1] [arg2] [arg3]
12-06 20:15:35.090 27948-27948/? I/subsystem_ramdump: [arg1]: (1/2) Ramdump location: 1: eMMC: /data/ramdump or 2: SD card: /sdcard/ramdump
12-06 20:15:35.090 27948-27948/? I/subsystem_ramdump: [arg2]: (1/0) 1: Enable RPM log / 0: Disable RPM log
12-06 20:15:35.090 27948-27948/? I/subsystem_ramdump: [arg3]: (1/0) 1: Enable qdss ramdump / 0: Disable qdss ramdump
12-06 20:15:35.090 27948-27948/? I/subsystem_ramdump:  Using default ramdump location 1: eMMC: /data/ramdump
12-06 20:15:35.090 27948-27948/? I/subsystem_ramdump:  Using default 0: Disable RPM log
12-06 20:15:35.090 27948-27948/? I/subsystem_ramdump:  Using default 0: Disable qdss ramdump
12-06 20:15:35.090 27948-27948/? E/subsystem_ramdump: Unable to open /dev
12-06 20:15:35.090 27948-27948/? E/subsystem_ramdump: Failed to find pil ramdump
12-06 20:15:35.399 652-694/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
12-06 20:15:35.446 704-945/? W/XTCC-5.1.0.13: [CS-RIL-LISTENER] timerCallback fired for ril update registering, re-register
12-06 20:15:35.447 652-694/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
12-06 20:15:37.058 3017-3017/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :1signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 30 -82 -11 130 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
12-06 20:15:38.118 27839-27839/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
12-06 20:15:38.345 3017-3017/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :0signalStrength=SignalStrength: 27 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
12-06 20:15:38.862 652-694/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XTWiFi-PE] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
12-06 20:15:39.118 27839-27839/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
12-06 20:15:39.206 23493-23636/? I/PlayCommon: [23158] PlayEventLogger.uploadEventsImpl: Preparing logs for uploading
12-06 20:15:39.206 23493-23636/? I/PlayCommon: [23158] PlayEventLogger.uploadEventsImpl: No file ready to send
12-06 20:15:39.627 3017-3017/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :1signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 30 -80 -12 40 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
12-06 20:15:40.093 28045-28045/? W/subsystem_ramdu: type=1400 audit(0.0:174251): avc: denied { read } for name="/" dev="tmpfs" ino=10822 scontext=u:r:subsystem_ramdump:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
12-06 20:15:40.108 28045-28045/? I/subsystem_ramdump: Usage:./system/bin/subsystem_ramdump [arg1] [arg2] [arg3]
12-06 20:15:40.108 28045-28045/? I/subsystem_ramdump: [arg1]: (1/2) Ramdump location: 1: eMMC: /data/ramdump or 2: SD card: /sdcard/ramdump
12-06 20:15:40.108 28045-28045/? I/subsystem_ramdump: [arg2]: (1/0) 1: Enable RPM log / 0: Disable RPM log
12-06 20:15:40.108 28045-28045/? I/subsystem_ramdump: [arg3]: (1/0) 1: Enable qdss ramdump / 0: Disable qdss ramdump
12-06 20:15:40.108 28045-28045/? I/subsystem_ramdump:  Using default ramdump location 1: eMMC: /data/ramdump
12-06 20:15:40.108 28045-28045/? I/subsystem_ramdump:  Using default 0: Disable RPM log
12-06 20:15:40.108 28045-28045/? I/subsystem_ramdump:  Using default 0: Disable qdss ramdump
12-06 20:15:40.108 28045-28045/? E/subsystem_ramdump: Unable to open /dev
12-06 20:15:40.108 28045-28045/? E/subsystem_ramdump: Failed to find pil ramdump
12-06 20:15:40.119 27839-27839/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
12-06 20:15:40.400 652-694/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
12-06 20:15:40.447 704-945/? W/XTCC-5.1.0.13: [CS-RIL-LISTENER] timerCallback fired for ril update registering, re-register
12-06 20:15:40.447 652-694/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
12-06 20:15:40.923 5007-5007/? W/perfd: type=1400 audit(0.0:174252): avc: denied { kill } for capability=5 scontext=u:r:perfd:s0 tcontext=u:r:perfd:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0
12-06 20:15:41.119 27839-27839/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
12-06 20:15:41.505 19594-19594/? I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
12-06 20:15:41.505 19594-19594/? I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
12-06 20:15:42.120 27839-27839/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
12-06 20:15:42.184 3017-3017/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :1signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 31 -76 -11 172 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
12-06 20:15:43.120 27839-27839/? W/Atfwd_Sendcmd: AtCmdFwd service not published, waiting... retryCnt : 2
12-06 20:15:43.862 652-694/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XTWiFi-PE] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
12-06 20:15:44.746 3017-3017/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :0signalStrength=SignalStrength: 28 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
12-06 20:15:45.127 28125-28125/? I/subsystem_ramdump: Usage:./system/bin/subsystem_ramdump [arg1] [arg2] [arg3]
12-06 20:15:45.127 28125-28125/? I/subsystem_ramdump: [arg1]: (1/2) Ramdump location: 1: eMMC: /data/ramdump or 2: SD card: /sdcard/ramdump
12-06 20:15:45.127 28125-28125/? I/subsystem_ramdump: [arg2]: (1/0) 1: Enable RPM log / 0: Disable RPM log
12-06 20:15:45.127 28125-28125/? I/subsystem_ramdump: [arg3]: (1/0) 1: Enable qdss ramdump / 0: Disable qdss ramdump
12-06 20:15:45.127 28125-28125/? I/subsystem_ramdump:  Using default ramdump location 1: eMMC: /data/ramdump
12-06 20:15:45.127 28125-28125/? I/subsystem_ramdump:  Using default 0: Disable RPM log
12-06 20:15:45.127 28125-28125/? I/subsystem_ramdump:  Using default 0: Disable qdss ramdump
12-06 20:15:45.127 28125-28125/? E/subsystem_ramdump: Unable to open /dev
12-06 20:15:45.127 28125-28125/? E/subsystem_ramdump: Failed to find pil ramdump
12-06 20:15:45.113 28125-28125/? W/subsystem_ramdu: type=1400 audit(0.0:174253): avc: denied { read } for name="/" dev="tmpfs" ino=10822 scontext=u:r:subsystem_ramdump:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
12-06 20:15:45.400 652-694/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
12-06 20:15:45.447 704-945/? W/XTCC-5.1.0.13: [CS-RIL-LISTENER] timerCallback fired for ril update registering, re-register
12-06 20:15:45.448 652-694/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
12-06 20:15:46.662 3017-3017/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :1signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 31 -75 -10 92 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
12-06 20:15:48.531 23493-23502/? W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.941ms
12-06 20:15:48.804 3619-3619/? I/PowerKeeperBackgroundService: onStartCommand()
12-06 20:15:48.804 3619-3619/? I/PowerKeeperService: onAlarm
12-06 20:15:48.862 652-694/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XTWiFi-PE] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
12-06 20:15:48.951 25547-25679/? W/ctxmgr: [ContextSpecificAclFactory]LocationConsent failed, ULR opt-in status is: false, account#103440244#
12-06 20:15:48.951 25547-25679/? W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#103440244#, com.google.android.gms(10015):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10084000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#103440244#
12-06 20:15:48.955 25547-25718/? W/ContentTaskController: Invalid task was provided to stopTracking.
12-06 20:15:48.991 1429-3453/? D/WifiService: acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@b3d1919}
12-06 20:15:48.998 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SCAN TYPE=ONLY'
12-06 20:15:48.998 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Setting scan request: 0.000000 sec
12-06 20:15:48.998 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: global_ctrl_sock-sendto: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=0 send_len=3
12-06 20:15:48.999 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Starting AP scan for wildcard SSID
12-06 20:15:48.999 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Add radio work 'scan'@0x558d7c5680
12-06 20:15:48.999 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
12-06 20:15:48.999 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Starting radio work 'scan'@0x558d7c5680 after 0.000064 second wait
12-06 20:15:48.999 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: nl80211: scan request
12-06 20:15:48.999 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Scan SSID - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
12-06 20:15:48.999 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Scan extra IEs - hexdump(len=7): 7f 05 00 00 0a 02 01
12-06 20:15:49.001 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
12-06 20:15:49.001 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Event message available
12-06 20:15:49.001 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Drv Event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) received for wlan0
12-06 20:15:49.001 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: nl80211: Scan trigger
12-06 20:15:49.001 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Event SCAN_STARTED (47) received
12-06 20:15:49.001 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Own scan request started a scan in 0.000179 seconds
12-06 20:15:49.001 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: ctrl_sock-sendmsg: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=0 send_len=24
12-06 20:15:49.001 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_ctrl_628-51\x00
12-06 20:15:49.001 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: ctrl_sock-sendmsg: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=768 send_len=24
12-06 20:15:49.001 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_ctrl_1429-2\x00
12-06 20:15:49.010 1429-3421/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 28195:com.google.android.talk/u0a64 for service com.google.android.talk/com.google.android.apps.hangouts.concurrent.impl.GcmTriggeredNotifier
12-06 20:15:49.011 3381-3449/? D/WtProcessController: onAMProcStart callback
12-06 20:15:49.017 25547-25690/? I/GCoreUlr: Successfully inserted 1 locations
12-06 20:15:49.057 28195-28195/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
12-06 20:15:49.155 25547-27353/? W/ContentTaskController: Invalid newTask was provided to startTracking.
12-06 20:15:49.264 25547-25556/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 221813(12MB) AllocSpace objects, 104(2MB) LOS objects, 37% free, 26MB/42MB, paused 2.209ms total 151.136ms
12-06 20:15:49.282 25547-25554/? E/DataBuffer: Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@cbba886)
12-06 20:15:49.282 25547-25554/? E/DataBuffer: Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@6e3c547)
12-06 20:15:49.299 25547-25554/? E/DataBuffer: Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@100d174)
12-06 20:15:49.828 28195-28195/? I/Babel_telephony: TeleModule.onApplicationCreate
12-06 20:15:49.837 28195-28259/? I/Babel_SMS: MmsConfig: mnc/mcc: 405/15
12-06 20:15:49.837 28195-28259/? I/Babel_SMS: MmsConfig.loadMmsSettings
12-06 20:15:49.839 28195-28259/? I/Babel_SMS: MmsConfig.loadDeviceMmsSettings from API: mUserAgent=Android-Mms/2.0, mUaProfUrl=http://www.google.com/oha/rdf/ua-profile-kila.xml
12-06 20:15:49.839 28195-28259/? I/Babel_SMS: MmsConfig.loadFromDatabase
12-06 20:15:49.855 3017-3017/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :1signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 31 -74 -11 200 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
12-06 20:15:49.857 28195-28259/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: mmsconfig
12-06 20:15:49.858 28195-28259/? I/Babel_SMS: MmsConfig: no mmsconfig table android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: mmsconfig (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT key, value, type FROM mmsconfig WHERE numeric=?
12-06 20:15:49.858 28195-28259/? I/Babel_SMS: MmsConfig.loadFromResources
12-06 20:15:49.861 28195-28259/? E/Babel_SMS: canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc nullnull
12-06 20:15:49.861 28195-28259/? I/Babel_SMS: MmsConfig.loadMmsSettings: mUserAgent=Android-Mms/2.0, mUaProfUrl=http://www.google.com/oha/rdf/ua-profile-kila.xml
12-06 20:15:49.903 28195-28195/? I/Babel_Prime: wrapCrashReportingIntoUncaughtExceptionHandler
12-06 20:15:49.913 28195-28195/? I/Babel_App: Startup - clean
12-06 20:15:49.918 28195-28263/? I/Babel_Prime: isMemoryEnabled=false
12-06 20:15:49.918 28195-28263/? I/Babel_Prime: isTimerEnabled=false
12-06 20:15:49.918 28195-28263/? I/Babel_Prime: isCrashCounterEnabled=true
12-06 20:15:49.920 28195-28263/? I/Babel_Prime: primesPackageConfigurationsProvider=false
12-06 20:15:49.962 1429-3458/? D/CryptdConnector: SND -> {542 cryptfs cryptocomplete}
12-06 20:15:49.962 405-417/? I/Ext4Crypt: ext4 crypto complete called on /data
12-06 20:15:49.963 405-417/? I/Ext4Crypt: No master key, so not ext4enc
12-06 20:15:49.965 1429-2896/? D/CryptdConnector: RCV <- {200 542 0}
12-06 20:15:49.965 1429-3458/? D/CryptdConnector: SND -> {543 cryptfs getpwtype}
12-06 20:15:49.966 405-417/? D/VoldCryptCmdListener: cryptfs getpwtype
12-06 20:15:49.966 405-417/? I/Ext4Crypt: ext4 crypto complete called on /data
12-06 20:15:49.966 405-417/? I/Ext4Crypt: No master key, so not ext4enc
12-06 20:15:49.966 1429-2896/? D/CryptdConnector: RCV <- {213 543 default}
12-06 20:15:49.979 28195-28195/? I/Babel_Prime: startMemoryMonitor
12-06 20:15:50.037 28195-28195/? I/Babel_ConcService: Binding ConcurrentService
12-06 20:15:50.127 25547-25718/? W/ContentTaskController: Invalid task was provided to stopTracking.
12-06 20:15:50.133 28281-28281/? W/subsystem_ramdu: type=1400 audit(0.0:174254): avc: denied { read } for name="/" dev="tmpfs" ino=10822 scontext=u:r:subsystem_ramdump:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
12-06 20:15:50.142 28281-28281/? I/subsystem_ramdump: Usage:./system/bin/subsystem_ramdump [arg1] [arg2] [arg3]
12-06 20:15:50.142 28281-28281/? I/subsystem_ramdump: [arg1]: (1/2) Ramdump location: 1: eMMC: /data/ramdump or 2: SD card: /sdcard/ramdump
12-06 20:15:50.142 28281-28281/? I/subsystem_ramdump: [arg2]: (1/0) 1: Enable RPM log / 0: Disable RPM log
12-06 20:15:50.142 28281-28281/? I/subsystem_ramdump: [arg3]: (1/0) 1: Enable qdss ramdump / 0: Disable qdss ramdump
12-06 20:15:50.142 28281-28281/? I/subsystem_ramdump:  Using default ramdump location 1: eMMC: /data/ramdump
12-06 20:15:50.142 28281-28281/? I/subsystem_ramdump:  Using default 0: Disable RPM log
12-06 20:15:50.142 28281-28281/? I/subsystem_ramdump:  Using default 0: Disable qdss ramdump
12-06 20:15:50.142 28281-28281/? E/subsystem_ramdump: Unable to open /dev
12-06 20:15:50.142 28281-28281/? E/subsystem_ramdump: Failed to find pil ramdump
12-06 20:15:50.155 1429-1440/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 7689:com.miui.cloudservice/u0a50 (adj 15): empty #17
12-06 20:15:50.172 25547-25718/? W/ContentTaskController: Invalid task was provided to stopTracking.
12-06 20:15:50.174 1429-3005/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 7689
12-06 20:15:50.184 28195-28279/? I/Babel_ConcService: Acquired partial wake lock to keep ConcurrentService alive
12-06 20:15:50.185 28195-28279/? I/Babel_ConcService: Released partial wake lock as ConcurrentService became idle
12-06 20:15:50.200 28195-28283/? I/Babel_ConcService: Acquired partial wake lock to keep ConcurrentService alive
12-06 20:15:50.202 28195-28283/? I/Babel_ConcService: Released partial wake lock as ConcurrentService became idle
12-06 20:15:50.250 25547-25690/? W/ContentTaskController: Invalid newTask was provided to startTracking.
12-06 20:15:50.400 652-694/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
12-06 20:15:50.448 704-945/? W/XTCC-5.1.0.13: [CS-RIL-LISTENER] timerCallback fired for ril update registering, re-register
12-06 20:15:50.448 652-694/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
12-06 20:15:50.508 22697-22741/? I/qtaguid: Failed write_ctrl(t -1 0 -1) res=-1 errno=9
12-06 20:15:50.508 22697-22741/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket -1 with tag 0(0) for uid -1 failed errno=-9
12-06 20:15:50.508 22697-22741/? I/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocketFd(-1, 0, -1) failed with errno-9
12-06 20:15:50.620 3267-3652/? I/XiaomiFirewall: firewall pkgName:com.google.android.youtube, result:0x0
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Event message available
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Drv Event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) received for wlan0
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: nl80211: New scan results available
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Scan included frequencies: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 5180 5200 5220 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5745 5765 5785 5805 5825
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Scan completed in 1.957986 seconds
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Associated on 5805 MHz
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Associated with f0:79:59:ce:69:74
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Received scan results (4 BSSes)
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Scan results indicate BSS status with f0:79:59:ce:69:74 as associated
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 4932
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: BSS: Add new id 7392 BSSID f0:79:59:ce:69:70 SSID 'Network14'
12-06 20:15:50.959 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: ctrl_sock-sendmsg: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=0 send_len=43
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_ctrl_628-51\x00
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: ctrl_sock-sendmsg: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=768 send_len=43
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_ctrl_1429-2\x00
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: BSS: Add new id 7393 BSSID f0:79:59:ce:69:72 SSID 'Picsurely.com'
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: ctrl_sock-sendmsg: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=768 send_len=43
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_ctrl_628-51\x00
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: ctrl_sock-sendmsg: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=1536 send_len=43
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_ctrl_1429-2\x00
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: BSS: Add new id 7394 BSSID f0:79:59:ce:69:71 SSID 'Picsurely-Guest'
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: ctrl_sock-sendmsg: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=1536 send_len=43
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_ctrl_628-51\x00
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: ctrl_sock-sendmsg: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=2304 send_len=43
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_ctrl_1429-2\x00
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: BSS: last_scan_res_used=4/128
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Scan-only results received
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: ctrl_sock-sendmsg: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=1536 send_len=24
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_ctrl_628-51\x00
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: ctrl_sock-sendmsg: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=1536 send_len=24
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_ctrl_1429-2\x00
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Radio work 'scan'@0x558d7c5680 done in 1.961428 seconds
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SCAN_RESULTS'
12-06 20:15:50.960 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: global_ctrl_sock-sendto: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=0 send_len=300
12-06 20:15:50.961 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SCAN_RESULTS'
12-06 20:15:50.961 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: global_ctrl_sock-sendto: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=0 send_len=300
12-06 20:15:50.962 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: global_ctrl_sock-sendto: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=1280 send_len=2409
12-06 20:15:50.965 704-947/? W/XTCC-5.1.0.13: [WifiScanner] WiFi scan result : [1] AP's
12-06 20:15:51.033 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: EAPOL: EAP Session-Id not available
12-06 20:15:51.033 2978-2978/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: global_ctrl_sock-sendto: sock=11 sndbuf=212992 outq=0 send_len=279
12-06 20:15:51.059 3267-3652/? I/XiaomiFirewall: firewall pkgName:com.miui.analytics, result:0x0
12-06 20:15:51.092 1429-3005/? D/WifiService: releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@b3d1919}
12-06 20:15:51.093 25547-25690/? W/ctxmgr: [ContextSpecificAclFactory]LocationConsent failed, ULR opt-in status is: false, account#103440244#
12-06 20:15:51.093 25547-25690/? W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#103440244#, com.google.android.gms(10015):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10084000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#103440244#
12-06 20:15:51.133 22697-22741/? I/qtaguid: Failed write_ctrl(u -1) res=-1 errno=9
12-06 20:15:51.133 22697-22741/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket -1 failed errno=-9
12-06 20:15:51.133 22697-22741/? W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(-1) failed with errno -9
12-06 20:15:51.153 3267-3652/? I/XiaomiFirewall: firewall pkgName:com.facebook.katana, result:0x0
12-06 20:15:51.257 27764-28301/? W/Analytics-Core-ConfigServer: HttpResponse is empty
12-06 20:15:52.421 3017-3017/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :0signalStrength=SignalStrength: 29 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
12-06 20:15:52.427 3017-3017/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :1signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 31 -75 -10 86 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
12-06 20:15:52.954 23493-23502/? W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.795ms
12-06 20:15:53.120 27839-27839/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
12-06 20:15:53.355 23493-25148/? I/PlayCommon: [23224] PlayEventLogger.uploadEventsImpl: Preparing logs for uploading
12-06 20:15:53.355 23493-25148/? I/PlayCommon: [23224] PlayEventLogger.uploadEventsImpl: No file ready to send
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using placeholder images to display the ImageView before loaded images from the API.

Higher resolution phones take high RAM usage if the images are not added in the **drawable-nodpi**

The RAM kept the images loaded and due to which the spikes couldn't be seen in the Memory Monitor Tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where the memory leak is coming from. Try the following. Run your application and view the memory usage via the Memory Monitor tool.

[image]

Try to see what causes the spikes and that might be your issue.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zry4V.png This is my memory monitor. There doesn't seem to be spikes. It constantly keeps it at the same level. If I open a recyclerView, the app would lag or crash due to OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Try to drag the bar up a little higher so you can see out of how much total memory that is being used. @GauravShetty